# Hiding request information from url

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

What may be the best way to hide request information from URL in c# MVC? Please explain full process. I am not getting how to do this..Thanks.

Comment: It would be useful if you would also describe to the reader what you mean by "request information from url" and also what you have tried and need help understanding.

Comment: "request information" means something like http://657898:Student/List?id=2....so i don't want id be appear...

Comment: It might be that the following information may assist:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history  I get the feeling that the "replaceState()" method may do what you need.

Comment: You cannot hide it, but you can encrypt it. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110561/encrypt-query-string-including-keys

Answer (score 0):

you can modify your MVC app config file with the following tags:

```
 <system.webServer>
   <httpProtocol>
     <customHeaders>
       <clear/>
     </customHeaders>
   </httpProtocol>
 </system.webServer>
```

the clear option clears most of the response headers. if, by any chance, you can put your hands on the context object you can get the Response/Request properties and gain more control over this feature, for instance:

```
context.Response.ClearHeaders();
```