# How can we encrypt http get query parameters before sending to another site?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, http-get

I am sending a http get request from server side to another site. How can I encrypt all data before sending the request? How can I decrypt the parameters in the second site to read them back? What encryption do we generally use for this?

```
var response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
response.Redirect(string.Format("http://localhost:58372/Testsite?type={0}&requestxml={1}", type, requestXML));
```

Comment: Don't do HTTP GET but HTTP POST via SSL instead. Put the sensitive data into the body payload, not into the URL.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110561/encrypt-query-string-including-keys

Answer (score 0):

Convert the parameters into base64 encode / decode. Make sure u convert your all parameters to string.

**Encode**

```
 var plainTextBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringtoencode);
  return System.Convert.ToBase64String(plainTextBytes);
```

**Decode**

```
  var base64EncodedBytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(base64EncodedData);
  return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(base64EncodedBytes);
```