# encrypt parameters in @Html.ActionLink

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, encryption, razor

i am trying to encrypt my url id from `asp.net` `razor`

In my view I have the following `@Html.ActionLink`:

```
@Html.ActionLink(" ","index", "Home", new { id = Server.UrlEncode(item.ID.ToString()) }, new { @class = "fas fa-eye", @title = "Ver Detalle" })
```

With that I get the link as follows:

```
http://localhost:62201/Home/index/1
```

And the idea is to hide or encrypt the id for "more security", something like this:

```
http://localhost:62201/Home/index/unrecognizable_id
```

And then this is decoded in my `controller`

I appreciate your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to hide the Id,you can try to use form post:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <input hidden name="Id" value=@item.ID />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
}
```

result:
[image]

In addition,If you want to use encrypt,you can refer to the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110561/encrypt-query-string-including-keys).